# Tomcat fails to start using netbeans

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans

Whenever i try to run/debug my project using netbeans, i get the following error

```
Deployment error: Starting of Tomcat failed.
See the server log for details.
    at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:258)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.ExecutionChecker.performDeploy(ExecutionChecker.java:205)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.ExecutionChecker.executionResult(ExecutionChecker.java:123)
    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.execute.MavenCommandLineExecutor.run(MavenCommandLineExecutor.java:235)
    at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
```

But tomcat is started in the background.
Also when i try to start tomcat in debug mode, i get a "Tomcat" failed to start error but tomcat is started in the background.
I have changed the port several times but no luck. I have shut down my anti virus and windows defender but that doesn't help too. I have uninstalled and re installed netbeans 7.4 and 8.0.

PS: I have gone through several stackoverflow posts but couldn't find any answer to help me.

Server log

```
 Jul 22, 2014 1:18:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Jul 22, 2014 1:18:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Jul 22, 2014 1:18:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@20d04cf3')
Jul 22, 2014 3:12:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Jul 22, 2014 3:12:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Jul 22, 2014 3:12:25 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@136da584')
Jul 22, 2014 3:37:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
Jul 22, 2014 3:37:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
Jul 22, 2014 3:37:06 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache', 'org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache@ad0db19')
```

Comment: already runnung?have you checked it from your browser?

Comment: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=209939

Comment: nobalG Yes i checked it from the browser and before i re run, i make sure i shut the running tomcat process

Comment: Have you done as the exception says? What's in the server log?

Comment: Would you mind stating as to how are you running your project? Any special configuration done for tomcat!

Comment: StFS This is the last 3 lines of the server log                                                      INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jul 22, 2014 12:09:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 645 ms

Comment: shekhar Suman, no special configuration was done for tomcat.

Comment: @azdonald just type '@'in front of the name WHILE referring or interacting with some other person on SO,beacuse only then they will be notified that you answered to their comments

Comment: @azdonald-This auestion won't get solved until you add the server log detail(complete) in the question!

Answer (score 0):

Disabling ipv6 solved the issue for me. 
If you use windows 8 you have to do that in the registry. Windows 7 and below, there is an installer for that at the Microsoft fix it site

Answer (score 0):

In NetBeans on Tools > Servers, in Platform tab disable Use IDE Proxy Settings.

Answer (score 0):

I have been banging my head against a wall over this for a few days now.
At first, it would just hang out, waiting to deploy tomcat... forever. After all the troubleshooting a hard reset was the only thing that solved the issue, but it only solved it for a one-time run of the application.
The issue at hand is that the prompt for the user and password would not pop-up on my screen...
**The Only Fix I could find was to turn off the proxy in netbeans/preferences select "no proxy"... and just like that the web application deployed in seconds.**